# How should I workaround this since my build is being blocked as -->FAILURE: Build failed with an exception?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-test

[here's the code with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5WTN.png)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/patto/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 793
- What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:assembleDebug'.                         
> FlutterPlugin$_addFlutterTasks_closure18$_closure45$_closure46$_closure47
```

- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

```
BUILD FAILED in 7s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         9.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Also the package you are using (flutter_tools) has very low score on pub.dev and is still in beta. May I know why you are using this package?

Comment: i've included the code

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see, deleted my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem just today.

I fixed it by doing

`flutter upgrade`

then

`flutter doctor`

when I ran my Flutter app again it worked and the error was gone.

This was my output for `flutter doctor`:

```dart
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  246M  100  246M    0     0   750k      0  0:05:36  0:05:36 --:--:-- 1292k
Building flutter tool...
Downloading package sky_engine...                                   2.6s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                            8.9s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                   10.9s
Downloading linux-x64 tools...                                     47.0s
Downloading linux-x64/font-subset tools...                          4.0s
Downloading android-arm-profile/linux-x64 tools...                  3.6s
Downloading android-arm-release/linux-x64 tools...                  2.3s
Downloading android-arm64-profile/linux-x64 tools...                2.8s
Downloading android-arm64-release/linux-x64 tools...                2.4s
Downloading android-x64-profile/linux-x64 tools...                  2.7s
Downloading android-x64-release/linux-x64 tools...                  2.5s
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
```

As you can see it built the flutter tool again and probably fixed it by doing so.

Comment: thanks...much appreciated, in future I'll keep that in mind

Comment: Alright. Do you mind marking the answer as correct?